# Problemas com Rotas no Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, rotas, angular-routes

tudo bem?
Estou iniciando meus estudos em angular e me deparei com um problema de rota.
Estou tentando criar novas rotas mas elas estão sendo carregadas abaixo do app principal ao invés de carregar a nova página.
Alguém saberia o que fazer?

```
<!-- Adicionando fonts -->

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Nag+Mundari:wght@400;500&family=Open+Sans&family=Roboto:wght@100;300;500;700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Adicionando icones -->

<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

<header class="centro" id="titulo">
    <h1>Venha conhecer nossos petmigo!</h1>
</header>

<nav id="nav">
    <ul id="lista">

        <li class="link"><a routerLink="adicionarPet">
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined">spa</span>
                    Adicionar pet a adoção
        </a>
            </li>

        <li class="link"><a routerLink="adicionarDetalhesPet"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">pets</span>
                Ver todos os pets
            </a></li>

        <li class="link"><a routerLink="removerPet"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">sound_detection_dog_barking</span>
                Adicionar mais detalhes do pet
            </a></li>

        <li class="link"><a routerLink="listarPets"><span class="material-symbols-outlined">free_cancellation</span>
                Retirar um pet da lista de adoção
            </a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>
```

Esse é o código do app.component

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-home-content></app-home-content>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Esse é o código do app-routing.module.ts

````
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdicionarComponent } from './components/adicionar/adicionar.component';
import { UpdateComponent } from './components/update/update.component';
import { DeleteComponent } from './components/delete/delete.component';
import { ListarComponent } from './components/listar/listar.component';

const routes: Routes = [
 {path:'', component:AppComponent},
 {path:'adicionarPet', component:AdicionarComponent},
 {path:'adicionarDetalhesPet', component: UpdateComponent},
 {path:'removerPet', component:DeleteComponent},
 {path:'listarPets', component:ListarComponent},
];

@NgModule({
 declarations: [],
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {} ```
````

Comment: Aparentemente este é o comportamento esperado. Os componentes são renderizado logo abaixo do `<router-outlet>`. Uma coisa que vi que vc fez errado foi adicionar o `AppComponent` as suas rotas. Normalmente ele é o componente raiz da sua aplicação e sempre estará na página, então se vc deixar deste jeito, ele vai ser renderizado 2 vezes. Mas explica melhor, vc queria que eles abrissem em uma nova aba quando clicasse nos links?